# Inverse trigonometic functions

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, derivatives, inverse-function

**Question:**

Prove that $\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{2} \tan2A)+\tan^{-1}(\cot A)+\tan^{-1}(\cot^{3} A)=0$

**MyProblem**

We can just use the formula of $\tan^{-1} A +\tan^{-1} B$ but I think it would be a waste of time. Is there any other shorter and simpler method to solve it.

Comment: Why do you think this is true? Is there some restriction on $A$?

Comment: Ideally the period is $\pi$ so analyse it there only.

Comment: @KingTut I have been only given to prove it.i don't know if it is true or false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint:

Prove that
$$\left(\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{2} \tan2A)+\tan^{-1}(\cot A)+\tan^{-1}(\cot^{3} A)\right)'=0$$ and check $A=\frac{\pi}{2}.$

Indeed, $$\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\tan2x\right)+\arctan\cot{x}+\arctan\cot^3x\right)'=$$
$$=\frac{\frac{1}{\cos^22x}}{1+\frac{1}{4}\tan^22x}+\frac{-\frac{1}{\sin^2x}}{1+\cot^2x}+\frac{3\cot^2x\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{\sin^2x}\right)}{1+\cot^6x}=$$
$$=\frac{4}{4\cos^22x+\sin^22x}-1-\frac{3\sin^2x\cos^2x}{\sin^6x+\cos^6x}=$$
$$=\frac{4}{4-3\sin^22x}-1-\frac{3\sin^2x\cos^2x}{1-3\sin^2x\cos^2x}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{1-3\sin^2x\cos^2x}-1-\frac{3\sin^2x\cos^2x}{1-3\sin^2x\cos^2x}=0.$$
Thus, our expression is a constant on all interval of the domain:
 $$(0,\pi)\setminus\left\{\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4}\right\},$$
for which it's enough to check $$x\in\left\{\frac{\pi}{8},\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{7\pi}{8}\right\},$$  which gives $\pi$ on $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$, $0$ on $\left(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)$ and $-\pi$ on $\left(\frac{3\pi}{4},\pi\right).$

Comment: This doesn't prove that given expression is $0$. It can be some other constant also..

Comment: I checked. The derivative indeed is equal to $0$ and the rest is an easy work.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I didn't ask for the values of x ,I needed you to prove it..Is my English so difficult to understand.Whatever, thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @CalculusProgrammer,  What if  $A=\dfrac\pi6$

Comment: @KingTut, It's $\pi$ Vide  the linked post

Comment: Yeah @lab sure it is.